# what is the difference between TARGET and TARGET_ARCH macros?

Tags: cross-compiling, freebsd

cross compiling FreeBSD for cavium boards having octeon chip supporting mips64 architecture so what should be the TARGET and TARGET_ARCH values as far as target_arch concerns it should be ((MIPS or MIPS64)?) but what about the TARGET macro?

considering its a big-endian

**env MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX=/home/bob/obj make buildworld TARGET=??? TARGET_ARCH=???**

Answer (score 2):

The TARGET is the hardware platform.
The TARGET_ARCH is the processor architecture.

An explanation is in `man uname`:

```
 The hardware platform (-m) can be different from the machine's processor
 architecture (-p), e.g., on 64-bit PowerPC, -m would return powerpc and
 -p would return powerpc64.
```

To figure out what are possible legal settings, display a list with `cd /usr/src; make targets`.